# How to split elements in a list Python

Tags: python

say i've got a list where each element contains more than 1 character like such:

```
ls = [" *X* ", " *** ", " W** "]
```

and I want to separate the multiple charactered elements into individual elements like this:

```
ls = [" * ", "X", " * ", " * ", " * ", " * ", "W", " * ", " * "]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Can you provide some logic — do you just want to separate everything into individual characters, or do the `*` have significance?

Comment: Are the spaces surrounding each character significant?

Comment: @MarkMeyer The * is a character in the original list where "  * X *  " are three characters in a single element. And now I want to split that up into three individual elements

Comment: @tzaman the spaces aren't significant, I had to include the spaces so the * character would show up in the post

Comment: @Turkey you don't need the spaces when it's formatted as code. It's very confusing with them in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
ls = ["*X*", "***", "W**"]
output = []
for i in ls:
    output.extend(list(i.strip()))

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested list comprehension is a quick and easy way to flatten:

```
ls = ["*X*", "***", "W**"]
flattened = [char for entry in ls for char in entry]
# Produces ['*', 'X', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'W', '*', '*']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add spaces around `*` items, and filter out empty spaces with `isspace()`:

```
>>> ls = [" *X* ", " *** ", " W** "]
>>> [f" {c} " if c == "*" else c for s in ls for c in s if not c.isspace()]
[' * ', 'X', ' * ', ' * ', ' * ', ' * ', 'W', ' * ', ' * ']
```

If we don't care about spaces around `*`, then we can simplify the above:

```
>>> [c for s in ls for c in s if not c.isspace()]
['*', 'X', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'W', '*', '*']
```

Also note the `[c for s in ls for c in s]` simply flattens the list.

Answer (score 0):

`ls = [" *X* ", " *** ", " W** "]`

```
def split(word): 
    return [char for char in word.strip() ] 

splitted_list = []
for word in ls:
        splitted_list.extend(split(word))

print(splitted_list)

['*', 'X', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'W', '*', '*']
```

Answer (score 0):

simple `join` + `split` will work

```
print (''.join(ls).split())
#['*', 'X', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'W', '*', '*']
```

if you are looking to have spaces in your elements

```
print ([i if i!='*' else f' {i} ' for i in ''.join(ls).replace(' ','')])
#[' * ', 'X', ' * ', ' * ', ' * ', ' * ', 'W', ' * ', ' * ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is my solution, as I realized in the comment you wanted to skip spaces and when the character is `*` you have to put it between spaces, here is my solution:

```py
ls = [" *X* ", " *** ", " W** "]
newls =[]
for ele in ls:
    for char in ele:
        if char==" ":
            continue;
        if char=="*":
            char=" "+char+" "
        newls.append(char)
print(newls)
```

And this is the output:
`[' * ', 'X', ' * ', ' * ', ' * ', ' * ', 'W', ' * ', ' * ']`

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions like this

```
ls = [" *X* ", " *** ", " W** "]
l = [x.strip() for sublist in ls for x in sublist if x.strip()]
print(l)
```

Output

```
['*', 'X', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'W', '*', '*']
```